# How to manage asynchronous state updates when using event handlers in render method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, react-hooks

Let me explain the goal of my code first. I have a react component called "Tile" containing a sub-component called "TileMenu" which shows up when I make a right click on my Tile, calling the function "openMenu". I wanted to have two ways of closing it:

- clicking somewhere else
- waiting some time

But, I also wanted it to stay in place if the mouse was over it. So I needed a function to cancel the timer, which I called "keepMenuOpened". If I moved my mouse away, openMenu() was called again to relaunch the timer.

Here is my code:

```
import TileMenu from './TileMenu'

function Tile() {


  const [openedMenu, setOpenedMenu] = useState(false);
    // state used to display —or not— the TileMenu component
  const [timeoutID, setTimeoutID] = useState(null);
    // state to store timeout ID and clear it


  function openMenu() {
    // Actually open TileMenu
    setOpenedMenu(true);

    // Prepare TileMenu closing
    window.onclick = closeMenu;
      // first case: click somewhere else
    setTimeoutID(setTimeout(closeMenu, 3000));
      // second case: time out
    console.log('open', timeoutID);
  }

  function closeMenu() {
    setOpenedMenu(false);

    window.onclick = null;
    console.log('close', timeoutID);
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }

  function keepMenuOpened() {
    console.log('keep', timeoutID);
    clearTimeout(timeoutID);
  }


  return(
    <>
      {openedMenu &&
      <TileMenu
        onMouseOver={keepMenuOpened} onMouseLeave={openMenu} // These two props are passed on to TileMenu component
      />}

      <textarea
        onContextMenu={openMenu}
      >
      </textarea>
    </>
  );
}

export default Tile
```

At first, it seemed to work perfectly. But I noticed that when I opened, then closed manually, and finally opened my TileMenu again, the delay it took to close a second time (this time alone) was calculated from the first time I opened it.

I used console.log() to see what was happening under the hood and it seemed to be caused by the asynchronous update of states in React (Indeed, at the first attempt, I get `open null` and `close null` in the console. When I move my mouse over the TileMenu and then leave it, I get for example `open 53`, then `keep 89` and then `open 89` !) If I understand well my specific case, React uses the previous state in openMenu and closeMenu but the current state in keepMenuOpened.

In fact, this is not my first attempt and before using a react state, "timeoutID" was a simple variable. But this time, it was inaccessible inside keepMenuOpened (it logged `keep undefined` in the console) even if declared in Tile() scope and accessible in openMenu and closeMenu. I think it's because closeMenu is called from openMenu. I found on the net it was called a closure but I didn't figure out exactly how it worked with React.

And now I haven't figured out how to solve my specific problem. I found that I could use useEffect() to access my updated states but it doesn't work in my case where I need to declare my functions inside Tile() to use them as event handlers. I wonder if my code is designed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you don't reset when opening the menu.

You probably shouldn't store the timer id in state, it seems unnecessary. You also don't clear any running timeouts when the component unmounts, which can sometimes cause issues if you later enqueue state updates or other side-effects assuming the component is still mounted.

It's also considered improper to directly mutate the `window.click` property, you should add and remove event listeners.

You can use an `useEffect` hooks to handle both the clearing of the timeout ***and*** removing the window click event listener in a cleanup function when the component unmounts.

```
function Tile() {
  const [openedMenu, setOpenedMenu] = useState(false);
  const timerIdRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
      clearTimeout(timerIdRef.current);
    }
  }, []);

  function openMenu() {
    setOpenedMenu(true);
    window.addEventListener('click', closeMenu);
    timerIdRef.current = setTimeout(closeMenu, 3000);
  }

  function closeMenu() {
    setOpenedMenu(false);
    window.removeEventListener('click', closeMenu);
    clearTimeout(timerIdRef.current);
  }

  function keepMenuOpened() {
    clearTimeout(timerIdRef.current);
  }

  return(
    <>
      {openedMenu && (
        <TileMenu
          onMouseOver={keepMenuOpened}
          onMouseLeave={openMenu}
        />
      )}

      <textarea onContextMenu={openMenu} />
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer allowed me to solve my problem but not in the expected way. I disagree on the first thing you say: that I need to reset the timer when opening the menu. If everything behaves correctly (which I admit is not certain), my timer is cleared before, in one of the two other functions.
In fact, my problem was solved by replacing useState() by useRef() as you do, I didn't need to change anything else. Do I still need to clear my timer in openMenu() for safety reasons?

Comment: @Cormor It is *always* a good idea to clear timers if they are no longer valid or useful/necessary. Depending on your use case you may want to also investigate creating/adding "click outside" logic by checking the origin of the click event's target and if the click originates from within the `TileMenu` component ignore the click and don't close the menu.

Comment: Also, there is a problem in your code with the useEffect part: it removes the timer immediately when openedMenu is set to true, so the menu never closes when opened for the first time. I had to put the two lines back in closeMenu() and to empty the dependency array, so that useEffect() is only executed on component unmount. May not be the best-looking solution but unless you find better, I suggest you to update your answer.

Comment: @Cormor Ah yeah, I went back and forth on empty dependency array and doing what you did and what I answered with. I didn't code it up to fully test it, only worked through it mentally and thought it made sense for your use case. I'll switch back the mounting effect version.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clear previous timer when `openMenu` called.

```js
function openMenu() {
  // clear previous timer before open
  clearTimeout(timeoutID);

  // Actually open TileMenu
  setOpenedMenu(true);

  // Prepare TileMenu closing
  window.onclick = closeMenu;

  // first case: click somewhere else
  setTimeoutID(setTimeout(closeMenu, 3000));
  // second case: time out
  console.log('open', timeoutID);
}

function closeMenu() {
  setOpenedMenu(false);

  window.onclick = null;
  console.log('close', timeoutID);

  // timer callback has executed, can remove this line
  clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```